# SNMP call to shared printer

Tags: printing, server, snmp, lan, network-printers

I have a next LAN scheme:

```
<MyPC 10.220.0.x> --- <WinServ 2008r2 10.220.0.x> --- <Xerox WC 192.168.0.x>
```

Server has PrintServer role enabled and printer is shared. I want to monitor the printer's state/errors through SNMP but problem is that I haven't acess to printer directly because it is in a different network. I can operate with printer ONLY as a shared i.e. through printserver, so my question is - how I can make SNMP requests to shared printer? Is it possible?

Comment: I think you are more likely to get an answer on https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your network diagram is vague enough that they could all be on the same LAN.
If so lucky, then just set a static route to the 192.168 network on "My PC". eg.

```
route add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 IP-ADDRESS-OF-MY-PC
```

If you can ping your printer, then you can access it via SNMP, assuming
there are no firewalls on the printer disallowing this.

Comment: unfortunately they isn't in same LAN and I can't  ping my printers from my PC

Comment: @whizzzkey: Obviously if your computer and printer have no networking between them, then it won't work...

Answer (score 1):

If the device in the middle is routing the relevant traffic and the config on the printer allows it to respond to SNMP requests from outside its subnet then there's nothing to stop it from working.

But those are really big caveats, particularly the first one.

If you are doing any NAT on the box in the middle, then either replace it with a Linux box or proper router or find another problem to solve.

If it's not routing, then you need to [set this up](http://techgenix.com/how-configure-windows-2008-server-ip-routing/) (note that you want a STATIC route).

If it is routing already then you probably need to look at the firewall to make sure its allowing the traffic.

If that's all working then you need to look at the SNMP policy on the printer.